# R removePunctuation: but still have words listed with apostrophes

Tags: r

Using R, I've used `library(tm)` and `removePunctuation`, but I still have some words which contain an ' (apostrophe). Then I went back and tried this:

```
toSpace <- content_transformer(function (x , pattern ) gsub(pattern, " ", x))
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "'")
```

[image]

I've also tried stemming, but no luck.

Thanks inadvance

Comment: Can you show us several examples of words with punctuation you want to remove--and which punctuation you _don't_ want removed?

Comment: I just want all single apostrophes to be removed. I've managed to remove all other punctuation except for in the word "company's".

Comment: Please make this [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output. Using `dput` may be helpful, depending on your input.

Comment: That may not be an apostrophe in there, but that aside, are you sure you _want_ to remove it?  It seems like you might have some wanted punctuation in there in addition to unwanted punctuation.

Comment: From the image, it looks like it isn't technically an apostrophe (by "ASCII" standards), take a look at `?iconv`.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleiesen thank you. It looks like it wasn't technically an apostrophe afterall. All good now

Comment: And @r2evans thank you too

Comment: @KMO I didn't downvote you, but next time you post spend a few minutes making your question a bit more beautiful to look at.  We love questions like eye-candy here on SO.

Comment: Check out the help for removePunctuation(). It uses [:punct:], which might not find  all kinds of apostrophes. You could try setting ucp = TRUE to use unicode punctuation (which might or might not solve your problem). I use a custom removePunctuation() to solve a range of issues I had with version in tm.